# Div that fades in then slides after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a div that fades in then slides after a delay. I need the fade and slide to happen at the same time after the delay. Does anyone know if this is possible?
Here is what I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image1').hide();
    $('#image1').delay(2500).fadeIn('3000');
    $('#image1').animate({'margin-top': '150px'}, 1000);
});   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#image1').hide().delay(2500).queue(function(next) {
      $(this).fadeIn({duration:3000, queue:false}).animate({'margin-top':  '150px'}, {duration:3000, queue:false});
   });
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wd6QX/4/)**

Or better animate opacity;

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image1').hide().delay(2500).animate({marginTop: '150px', opacity: 1}, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I need (1st example), but the delay isn't working!

Comment: Hi @A.V. - Thanks - works perfectly. Just trying to work out what you changed so I can understand better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`fadeIn()` basically animates the opacity from 0 to 1, so just do that in your `animate()` function, or use the [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function to make custom animation queues :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image1').hide()
                .delay(2500) 
                .animate({
                      opacity  : 1, 
                      marginTop: '150px'
                }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need but the animation and opacity change still do not happen at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#image1').hide();
        $('#image1').delay(2500).animate({marginTop: '150px', opacity: 1}, 1000);
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, however the opacity and slide action do not happen at the same time again in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `slideDown`you don't need the `fadeIn` call.
So how about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image1').hide(); // If you start off with CSS hidden styles, this is not needed.
    $('#image1').delay(2500).slideDown(3000);
});
```

Note that you also don't need the `animate` call if you set the appropriate margin in your stylesheet.